# What is the best Django syncdb crash debugging technique?

Tags: django, exception, postgresql, syncdb

What is the best Django syncdb crash debugging technique ?

I've previously asked a question about a problem with manage.py syncdb returning an exception
and the answer was that the app has a wrong import.

[django manage.py syncdb not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734721/django-manage-py-syncdb-not-working)

I'd like to know the technique used to find the place where there is a wrong import.

I tried ./manage.py syncdb --verbosity=2 but I didn't get any more information that way.

Answer (score 1):

You look at the problem the other way around. 
syncdb doesnt have anythin to do with "import". You have misconfigured python or/and django install and this is a problem.
If you want to debug what happen with sql queries then you should use

```
python manage.py sqlall __yourappname__
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. When I say wrong import, I mean an import in the wrong place like you can see in this github commit:

http://github.com/kylef/django-request/commit/62d2254bc12a821a0bdd04b8e13532e9302f1d77