# Mac OSX Upgrade now Django Not Found

Tags: django, macos, installation, upgrade

I have been using an outdated Mac operating system (10.5.8), but recently updated to 10.8. However, now django isn't being found anymore.

Operations such as:

```
python manage.py runserver
```

that worked before now return:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

I [read another post here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734721/django-manage-py-syncdb-not-working) where the user suggested checking if django was available using `python -c 'import django'`. Django is not available using that command, and I tried to modify my PYTHONPATH to point to where the django package was (in my Downloads folder), but that didn't work either.

Anyways, I'm confused as to why it worked before but not now? Maybe because this version of OSX uses a different version of Python?

PS I am not using a virtualenv. Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: Have you tried just reinstalling Django using "pip install django"?

Comment: are you using virtualenv ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think when you upgraded to Mac OS X 10.8 your site-packages/ libraries were removed and now it sounds like you just need to install django again. Make `pip install django`.

Besides usage of virtualenv is a good practice to follow. In that particular case your virtualenv contained all necessary packages and you just had to install virtualenv instead of a bunch of libraries.

Answer (score 0):

When you upgraded OSX, you almost certainly got a new default version of Python. 10.5 had Python 2.5, but 10.8 has 2.7. Libraries are installed for a specific version, so you'll just need to reinstall with the new version.